# While Integrating Android App to Firebase remote config, how to use 2 google-services.json ( one for PROODUCTION and another for QA environment)?

Tags: android, firebase

If I create 2 sub folders under SRC (eg- QA and PROD and put the google-services.json file), will that be enough? How will App understand which file to pick for qa/production version of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using Application Flavours.

```
|--> app
|----> src
|------> main (this is where you 'base' product build goes
|--------> google-services.json (google services for main - Default)
|--------> res (res files for main - Default)

|------> qa (this is named the same as one of your flavours)
|--------> google-services.json (google services for qa)
|--------> res (res files for qa)
|----------> drawable-xxxhdpi (drawables for qa)
|----------> values (values files for qa, e.g. strings.xml)

|------> prod (this is named the same as one of your flavours)
|--------> google-services.json (google services for prod)
|--------> res (res files for prod)
|----------> drawable-xxxhdpi (drawables for prod)
|----------> values (values files for prod, e.g. strings.xml)
```

app build.gradle

```
...

flavorDimensions "main"
productFlavors {
    qa {
        applicationId = "com.your.appl.qa";
        versionNameSuffix "_QA"
    }
    prod {
        applicationId = "com.your.appl";
        versionNameSuffix "_PROD"
    }
}
...
```

You can then switch flavour in the Build Variants window:

[image: Build Variant Menu]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gavin for your suggestion. It worked!!

Comment: You can mark as the Answer that will then help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are one step behind to achieve this. Just use `productFlavors` for each build type in your module level `build.gradle`.

```
// Specifies one flavor dimension.
flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {
    PROD {

        ....
    }

    QA {

        ....
    }
}
```

**N.B:** Check [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to learn more about build variant

Comment: @user12489306. If it will help you then please accept the answer. Thanks